# Choppy svg animation

Tags: animation, svg, transition

I have created an animated SVG that works nice and smooth.

I do have Swiper slider installed on the website, and using this animation as slider transition, so when 'slideChangeTransitionStart' it run this animation or when to click on next or prev buttons do the same job, the only one issue I have that when t runs this animation it's a bit jerky and do not looks nice at all. I tried to find so many answers, but none of them helped.

I thought that might be it's a browser as it runs smoothly on firefox, but not really good on Chrome but event worse in Safari.

I would appreciate any advice or I need to go a different direction.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t8ttugquaszni7l/AACzUJBJmqy3jjhiRgNXozaea